# In what cartoon was Vandal Savage nearly killed?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, dc-animated-universe

I have a vague memory of a cartoon, but I am not sure if it was a film or TV show.  The climax involved Vandal Savage getting stuck by lightning or something like that. The other heroes thought he might be dead then like a horror film he jumps up screaming and is all zombie like from all the damage he just took.

Any ideas what TV episode or film this was (I do remember it was a cartoon version)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this could be the **Justice League episode Maid of Honor: Part II**. Savage has constructed an orbital rail gun, which uses passing meteors as ammo. He plans to use it to threaten the world into submission, and picks a US aircraft carrier group to sink as a demonstration of the power and accuracy of his weapon.

Savage picks Paris as a second target, but this time Batman reprograms the command to have it drop on top of Savage's location. He's buried, and they think he's dead (only just having learned that he's the same Savage from WWII, but not understanding that he's immortal in every sense), but **he gets up out of the rubble in a zombie-like fashion** (though he doesn't physically look like one).

On [Daily Motion](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3f7bg0) you can see it at around 20:00.

Comment: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3f7bg0 Couldn't find it on Youtube, but in this video it starts around 20 minutes.